# program with casting warning in function returning as many Xs as digits the input number has

Tags: c

I have been working on creating a C program that given a sequence of digits (provided as a char array), the program returns as many X as the number of digits the input contains (e.g. input: "1234"--> output:"XXXX")

The code I have written is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* getPlaceholder(char * word);

int main(){

char * myWords []={"111","22222","1113445","9"};
char ** mywords_pointer=myWords;

/*We will apply the function getPlaceholder to each of the components of the myWords array */

for (int indx=0; indx<3; indx++){
char *currentWord=*(mywords_pointer+indx);
const char *placeholder;
printf("Calling function\n");
placeholder=getPlaceholder(currentWord);
printf("The placeholder for %s is: %s\n",currentWord, placeholder);

}
return 0;
}


//getPlaceholder gets a number as a string and outputs as many Xs as digits the imput number has.  
const char* getPlaceholder(char * number){

char *ptr; 

long wordAsNumb=strtol(number,&ptr,10);/* in order to later be able to count the number of digits the input 'number' has*/

char *currentPlaceholder='\0';//this variable is initialised and later we will later be added new Xs in case the input number has more than one digit. 


"222"--> 222
'\0'
.X \0'

while (wordAsNumb>1){

size_t len=strlen(currentPlaceholder); //this is the variable which will contain the placeholder (Xs) corresponding to the input number
char *output_string=malloc(len+2); /* adds two new characters to fit a new X (to increase the number of digits the input number has) and the "\0" */


strcpy(output_string,currentPlaceholder);
output_string[len]='X';
output_string[len+1]='\0';
/* in order to copy the currentPlaceholder value to 'output_string'. Then we add the two nex characters in the array*/
printf("String output is now %s\n ",output_string);

strcpy(currentPlaceholder,output_string);
free (output_string);
wordAsNumb/=10;

}

const char* finalPlaceholder=currentPlaceholder;
return finalPlaceholder;

}
```

However, I have stumbled upon the warning:

```
initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

in line:

```
 char *output_string='X';
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong exactly?

Many thanks

Comment: In short, when defining an inline C-string you need to double quote the initial value. Here you have single quoted it, so the compiler attempts to treat it as an `int` instead of a null-terminated char array.

Comment: The title _"program with nesting warning in placeholder function_" appears to have no connection to the actual question.  What does that even mean?

Comment: @Clifford. You are completely right. I wrote nesting instead of casting. That has been fixed already

Comment: _"placeholder function"_ suggests a temporary function that will later be replaced.  That is not the sense you mean it here.  Even with the typo fixed, it is misleading. I don't think the actual function name or what it is intended to do is particularly relevant in any case.

Comment: You were all completely right in that the code was unclear and indeed with mistakes. I have added some comments that hopefully will make it clear. Hopefully now the idea of the code is clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal character-constants (in single quotes) have type `int`.

```
char output_char = 'X' ;
```

or

```
char* output_string = "X" ;
```

depending on the required semantics.  However here the required semantics are ambiguous.  It is not clear what the initialisation or even the pointer itself is for as it is unused.  The later

```
char *output_string=malloc(len+2);
```

shadows it and makes it inaccessible.  Really you could just delete the entire declaration.

To be honest, the rest of the code makes little sense and has serious errors.  It will crash:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
```

but that is a different question.